# How to make SOAP Api client request?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I just need to make the call.
http://api.linnlive.com/stats.asmx?op=SimpleGenericQuery

I want to use that, within a web page, to run a query and return the data, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://api.linnlive.com/stats">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:SimpleGenericQueryCSV>
<ns1:Token>INSERT YOUR TOKEN HERE</ns1:Token>
<ns1:sqlQuery>select * from stockitem where blogicaldelete = '1'</ns1:sqlQuery>
</ns1:SimpleGenericQueryCSV>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But what do I do?

I've tried making an xml file and doing something like this:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("/lookup.xml");
echo "result: ".$xml
?>
```

But I get a blank, any ideas? What is the correct way?

Comment: Obvious syntax error. Did you ever check ?

Comment: I have checked it. But no result. Can you tell me what type of syntax error?

Comment: @Raptor I have also tried with this code 
    $Token ='0CF7E072386B';
    $sqlQuery = 'select * from stockitem where blogicaldelete = "1"';


    $url = 'http://api.linnlive.com/stats.asmx?wsdl';
    //$url = 'http://api.linnlive.com/inventory.asmx?wsdl';

    $client = new soapclient($url);
    $response = $client->__call('SimpleGenericQuery',     array('Token'=>$Token,'sqlQuery'=>$sqlQuery));  
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($response);
exit;

Comment: You can add the codes in your question using **edit** feature.